# View css styles originating from user agent style sheet in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet, user-agent

Is there a way in IE9 to see styles that are originating from the user agent?

Similar to firebug's [show user agent css](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel#User_agent_rules) feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I thumbled accros a nice site. [Internet Explorer User Agent Style Sheets](http://www.iecss.com/)

You can find there all user agent styles of the last IE Versions listed in a nice table. Of course you can open developer tools on any major browser by hitting <kbd>F12</kbd>

[image: IECSS.com snapshot]

Within **IE11** you'll see a picture as shown below. Navigate to *DOM Explorer* open *Calculated Style* at the right hand and disable options marked with red.

[image: IE11 developer tools]

Right now I can't find a working IE9 installation on one of my computers. So I hope this may still be of any use for you.

Comment: iecss.com has replaced their site and all the linked stylessheets with a blog. See also: https://meiert.com/en/blog/user-agent-style-sheets/